How to set default value for custom pageable?
I have a custom pageable like this
@JsonProperty private Integer page = DEFAULT_PAGE; @JsonProperty private Integer rpp = DEFAULT_RPP; @JsonIgnore public int getOffset() {    return (getPage() - 1) * getRpp(); } @JsonIgnore public final int getNumberOfRows() {   return getRpp(); }}

public Response<ResponsePageable<ProvinceDTO>> getProvinces(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "empty") String provinceCode,@RequestParam(defaultValue = "empty") String provinceEnglish,RequestPageable pageable)

i want the default value when reload in swagger is page :!and rpp :!0 but in swagger the default value is still page:0 and rpp:0 please help me
